# Generate Spring context files from template

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have a lot of repeating beans in my context definition files where only the names are different.

So when I want definition for the beans a, b and c I have to add:

```
<bean id="a" class="org.project.A" />
<bean id="b" class="org.project.B" />
<bean id="c" class="org.project.C" />
<bean id="aDao" class="org.project.ADAO" />
<bean id="bDao" class="org.project.BDAO" />
<bean id="cDao" class="org.project.CDAO" />
```

As there are many more than 3 beans, I want something like:

```
bean: a,b,c
templates:
- <bean id=":bean:" class="org.project.:bean:upper:" />
- <bean id=":bean:Dao" class="org.project.:bean:upper:DAO" />
```

Is there already a way to do this in Spring?
And if I have to implement my own solution, how can I make Spring call this function before trying to import the generated files?

Comment: **Critical Info** from comments below: there are many beans being generated from the same class.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such functionality in Spring. You can write a maven plugin or some other pre-processing tool that searches for beans and generates the XML file.

Or you can let the Spring do this and drop the XML definitions altogether by annotating your beans with `@Service`, `@Repository` and friends.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [annotation based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) you don't need to generate the bean definition xml elements.

Comment: I don't think annotating the classes would work, as I also have up to 60 beans from the same class, only with different bean id and different property values.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I used Apache Velocity to generate config for an IoC framework using a template file. The template language is simple yet powerful.
You may implement it as a Java app, call it from Ant, etc.

http://velocity.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

The last time I checked (several years ago), Spring used the following (simplified) algorithm to create beans:

1. Read XML files to get bean definition. The beans are *not* created immediately. Instead, their definitions are held in some data structures that later (in step 4) will be queried to create the beans.
2. Spring iterates over each bean definition, and uses reflection to check if a bean's class implements the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` interface.
3. If so, that bean is created and its `postProcessBeanFactory()` operation is invoked. That method is typically coded to iterate over all the bean definitions and modify some of them, for example, to replace `"${property.value}"` with the value of a property read from a Java properties file.
4. Afterwards, the remaining ("normal") beans are created according to the (possibly modified) bean definitions.

It's been several years since I last looked at Spring, but *if* it still operates in the same way, then it might be possible to implement a class that implements the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` interface and codes `postProcessBeanFactory()` to append a bean's `id` property onto its `class` property.